# Getting values from html select in views.py in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm newbie in Django and i would like to have a little help please. I want to get the values that users select in the from *select options* and use that in my views.py. However, I've been unsuccessful. How can I get that values that the users select? Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

My product.html:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ object.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                      {% for var in object.variation_set.all %}
                        <h5>Choose {{ var.name }}</h5>
                          <select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" title="variations">
                          {% for item in var.itemvariation_set.all %}
                              <option value="{{ item.value }}">{{ item.value|capfirst }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                          {% endfor %}
                    <div class="action">
                      <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
                      <button class="like btn btn-danger" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

My views.py:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'products/product.html'

@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user= request.user,
        ordered=False,
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
            messages.success(request, "Product quantity has been updated.")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
            messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
            return redirect("order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
        messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
        return redirect("order-summary")
    return redirect("order-summary")
```

Comment: access using `form.cleaned_data['field_name']` in your views.py.
Here is a reference in case you want to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: It is not a django form, just an html input form

Comment: can you paste your view here which renders this HTML?

Comment: Yes sure I edited it 
I've added both the view that renders the html file, and the add_to_cart view in which I want to get the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change *title* to *name* `<select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" title="variations">` to

`<select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" name="variations">`